# Is ROS able to cancel the limit of karma to upload pictures?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the new user of ROS have some pictures to describe question clearly,it is very sad to see that he doesn't have enough karma to upload pictures.

So I ask if there is possible to make new user also can upload pictures to describe his/her questions.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11197/is-ros-able-to-cancel-the-limit-of-karma-to-upload-pictures?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The karma requirement to upload is an anti-spam/abuse measure.  The current requirement is 20 points to upload, which is only two upvotes, or several comments.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-09-17**:
There a number of online services that you could upload a picture to and then post a link to that hosted image. For example, http://imgur.com/ , http://imageshack.us/ or even a public gallery on something like Picasa or Dropbox.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-16**:
For example: this link: http://answers.ros.org/question/2144/rviz-sensor-data-does-not-rotate  ,  which doesn't have permit to upload picture,so he uses a lot of words to describe it. I also have similar question,but failed to compare with this question.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-16**:
Karma couldn't prevent spam message,why just prevent picture uploading? Is picture upload will cause big problem for ROS server? Thank you~